# How to pass command line parameters to 'pub upgrade' from flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting an error when running 'flutter pub upgrade'.

```
HTTP error 404: Not Found
package:pub/src/http.dart 218:5  _ThrowingClient.send

This is an unexpected error. Please run
    pub --trace '--verbosity=warning' upgrade --no-precompile
and include the logs in an issue on https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/new
```

Trying to add the respective parameters does not work because I am using:
flutter pub upgrade.

Is there a possibility to add command line parameters to '**flutter pub upgrade**' which are then passed over to '**pub upgrade**'?

---

As specified in the comment `flutter pub upgrade -v` is passing over the additional parameters. However it did not give me any hint what the problem is. Below is the output of `flutter pub upgrade -v`:

$ flutter pub upgrade -v
[  +31 ms] executing: [c:\bin\flutter] git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +88 ms] Exit code 0 from: git log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] b712a172f9694745f50505c93340883493b505e5
[        ] executing: [c:\bin\flutter] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[  +73 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] v1.7.8+hotfix.3-0-gb712a172f
[  +10 ms] executing: [c:\bin\flutter] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +68 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [c:\bin\flutter] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +60 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +90 ms] executing: [c:\bin\flutter] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +66 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +70 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +6 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +6 ms] Running "flutter pub upgrade" in xxxxx...
[   +3 ms] Using c:\bin\flutter.pub-cache for the pub cache.
[   +1 ms] executing: [D:\Projects\xxxxx] c:\bin\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat --verbosity=warning --verbose upgrade --no-precompile
[+7197 ms] HTTP error 404: Not Found
[  +11 ms] package:pub/src/http.dart 218:5                 _ThrowingClient.send
[   +1 ms] ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[   +1 ms] dart:async                                      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError
[   +1 ms] package:pub/src/http.dart                       _ThrowingClient.send
[   +1 ms] ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[   +1 ms] dart:async                                      _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[   +1 ms] package:pub/src/http.dart                       _ThrowingClient.send
[   +1 ms] package:http_throttle/http_throttle.dart 33:31  ThrottleClient.send
[   +1 ms] ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[   +1 ms] dart:async                                      _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[   +1 ms] package:http_throttle/http_throttle.dart        ThrottleClient.send
[   +1 ms] package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 322:37       BoundHostedSource._download
[   +1 ms] ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[   +1 ms] dart:async                                      _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[        ] package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart                 Entrypoint.acquireDependencies
[   +1 ms] package:pub/src/command/upgrade.dart 43:22      UpgradeCommand.run
[   +1 ms] This is an unexpected error. Please run
[   +1 ms]     pub --trace '--verbosity=warning' --verbose upgrade --no-precompile
[        ] and include the logs in an issue on https://github.com/dart-lang/pub/issues/new
[  +20 ms] pub upgrade failed (69) -- attempting retry 1 in 1 second...

Comment: whats is the output of `flutter pub upgrade -v`?

Comment: I found the reason for the issue. We were using a dependency from an in-house host which did not have the respective package. However the output from flutter pub upgrade -v did not give more details.